# Xaomi killing foreground service

Tags: java, android, android-studio, foreground

I want to take the location of the users. I did the foreground service and works on every phone. But xaomi phones, if the application is not in the background is turning off the foreground service. I tried everything I turned on the auto launcher. I've allowed everything to be allowed through the settings, but it won't. I've been trying for a month, please help.

Comment: https://dontkillmyapp.com/xiaomi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you using alarms.

You can use services to continue executing code in background and wakelocks but I had the same problem you described with several specific smartphones and also found out that services can be killed at any moment if the android system requires free memory.

The solution I found was to use alarms (an alarm that executes the foreground service). If you schedule alarms this alarms will go off whether your app is still executing or not. That way the app can get the device position even though the system had killed the service due to lack of resources. It's the only solution I found that worked in this scenario.

The idea came to me in some google i/o when they said that if you really need your app to continue no matter what you should use alarms instead of services.

Use exact amarms as inexact ones sometimes take, at least, 5 minutes in some devices until the alarm goes off.

This worked for me but I did it 2-3 years ago. I hope it still works.